# AWS SNS notification when an SES identify is fully verified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm creating new AWS SES identities (domain identities) programmatically, using the AWS API. After one is created, SES periodically checks for the existence of DNS records to verify the domain. My app also has to periodically poll SES to check if the domain has been fully verified.

Instead of polling, is there a way to create an SNS topic which will notify my app when the identity is fully verified?